# Property 'getChats' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, deployment

I am getting this error in typescript when tryig to access group.getUsers() or group.getChat().If I compile this code it runs fine in javascript.Its just that typescript can't identify these methods

**this is how I specified relations between models**

```
Chat.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Chat)

User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: 'UserGroup' });
Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'UserGroup' });

Group.hasMany(Chat, { foreignKey: 'groupId' });
Chat.belongsTo(Group, { foreignKey: 'groupId' });
```

**and this is the my controller function in which I am getting error**

```
export const getGroupChat = async(req: customRequest, res: Response) =>{
    const uuid = req.params.id
    try{
        const group = await Group.findOne({
            where : {
                uuid : uuid
            }
        })
        if(!group){
            res.status(200).json('Err Occured')
            return;
        }
        const users = await group.getUsers()
        const chats = await group.getChats()
        console.log(users, chats)
    }catch(Err){
        console.log(Err)
    }
}
```

These are my models
**Chat**

```
import Sequelize  from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../utils/database";

const Chat = sequelize.define('chats', {
    id : {
        type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey : true,
        autoIncrement  : true
    },
    message : Sequelize.STRING
})

export default Chat
```

**User**

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";

import sequelize from "../utils/database"

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id : {
        type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement : true,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey : true
    },
    name : Sequelize.STRING, 
    email : {
        type : Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull : false,
        unique: true
    }, password : {
        type : Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

export default User
```

**Group**

```
import  Sequelize  from "sequelize";
import sequelize from "../utils/database";

const Group = sequelize.define('groups', {
    id : {
        type : Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull : false,
        primaryKey : true,
        autoIncrement  : true
    },
    uuid : Sequelize.STRING,
    name : Sequelize.STRING,
    description : Sequelize.STRING
})

export default Group
```

I tried defining type of group as any but still same result

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that TypeScript cannot infer the types for the `getUsers` and `getChats` methods on the `Group` model. These methods come from Sequelize, but TypeScript doesn't know that.

To fix this, you need to tell TypeScript what the shape of the `Group` model is. You can do this by creating an interface:

```
interface GroupModel extends Model {
  getUsers(): Promise<User[]>;
  getChats(): Promise<Chat[]>; 
}
```

This interface extends `Model` (from Sequelize) and adds the missing methods.

Then when defining `Group`, assert that it matches this interface:

```
const Group = sequelize.define<GroupModel>('groups', {
  // ...
});
```

Now TypeScript will know that `Group` has the `getUsers` and `getChats` methods.